# How to post a form, from HTTPS to HTTP without getting warning messages in Firefox

Tags: http, firefox, https

I have a Internet payment api runs in https. After processed the payment need to redirect client website which runs in http. In this case Mozilla Firefox pop-up below warning message.

"Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"

Is there any solution to prevent it?